# How to find Kendo Grid Id on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have button in my Toolbar and that Toolbar in my Layout page and i have kendo grids in other views. When i click button i want export that grid to Excel.

How to get any kendo Grid Id and export that Excel with that button?

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I am going to make some assumptions based on your question.

I am going to assume you have a `toolbar` widget on the page that is not linked to the view that holds the `grid` widget(s). Now the grid's themselves have an automatic export to excel button that you can configure in the widget's configuration. [Export To Excel From Grid](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/excel-export)
But as an example here is a dojo that shows you linking this to an `external` button outside of the grid. [Dojo Example](https://dojo.telerik.com/oWEXEdaz)

All I have done is created a function that will find any `grid widgets` on the page and then export them to excel for you. Now this will only export the `first page` for you but you can configure the grid to export all pages prior to the `saveToExcel()` function being run.

Here is the function I created for clarity:

```
function(e) {
  var grids = $('div[data-role="grid"]');

  if (grids.length > 0) {
    grids.each(function(index, foundGrid) {

      $(foundGrid).data('kendoGrid').saveAsExcel();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what i want. Thanks man!!!!